# Angular universal window is not defined

Tags: angular, angular8, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

im trying to run SSR on my angular8 project but when i run server.js this error happens

```sh
    home/daba/client/dist/server/main.js:288235
})(window, document, 'Hammer');
^

ReferenceError: window is not defined
at Object.yLV6 (/home/daba/client/dist/server/main.js:288235:4)
at webpack_require (/home/daba/client/dist/server/main.js:20:30)
at Object.ZAI4 (/home/daba/client/dist/server/main.js:171354:1)
at webpack_require (/home/daba/client/dist/server/main.js:20:30)
at Object.V7fC (/home/daba/client/dist/server/main.js:161821:10)
at webpack_require (/home/daba/client/dist/server/main.js:20:30)
at Object.K011 (/home/daba/client/dist/server/main.js:125145:37)
at webpack_require (/home/daba/client/dist/server/main.js:20:30)
at Object.0 (/home/daba/client/dist/server/main.js:1251:18)
at webpack_require (/home/daba/
client/dist/server/main.js:20:30)
`
```

i've tried many things but still nothing

Answer (score 1):

Server-side applications can't reference browser-only global objects such as window, document, navigator, or location. You must check whether the code runs on the server or the client side:

```
constructor(
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object
)

...
myFunction() {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
        // do something with window here
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a generic solution which do not help when importing hammerjs into a universal project. The library has a dependency to the window object and it is executed as soon as you call `import * as Hammer from 'hammerjs'`. This import is required to inject a custom hammer config in the app.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add this code to your server.ts before `const app = express();`? It may help to avoid exceptions from thirty party libraries which don't allow using them on server-side.

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as domino from 'domino';

const template = fs.readFileSync('browser/index.html').toString();
const win = domino.createWindow(template);

global['window'] = win;
global['document'] = win.document;
global['navigator'] = win.navigator;
global['Event'] = null;
```